why does my wifi think my desktop is 10 different devices and why does each one have a different ip address?
myspectrum app
clicked on internet
clicked on services
manage devices
It lists my desktop 10 times
each one has a different ip and mac address
why does it think i have 10 different devices? It is the same device. my home desktop. Is this normal?

Can you provide a redacted screenshot?

as for the IP addresses, most DHCP servers will attempt to grant the same MAC address the same IP over multiple sessions, as long as there are plenty of free addresses to give out, and the record is only so old. they'll only guarantee that a particular mac will get a given IP if a reservation is configured, but for small networks that is often unnecessary to keep the same IP for a long period of time. So, if the MAC address changes, the IP issued by DHCP is likely to change as well.

what do I redact? and im not sure how to upload a screenshot? i tried to copy paste and it didnt work

Well, if you're running modern OSes, windows included, they have an option for randomised MAC addresses as a privacy option. Since many routers are going to give a different IP per mac address, its going to see 'each' new MAC address as a different system.
This makes a lot of sense on a laptop or phone since someone could track you by your MAC address at the router in theory. On a desktop you're using at home, less so.
On windows, you can go to settings -> network and internet and turn Random hardware addresses off

